# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

Hello I have ParseException when I try to use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
this.firstTweetTime = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm",Locale.US).parse(array[4]);
```

where `array[4]` is a string from text file I read and it is like this: `12/8/2010 11:48`

I get the following error:
[image]
I cannot understand what went wrong. can you please help me.

Comment: It looks like you've read the data from the file using the wrong character encoding.

Comment: At least one error is inside your pattern. You should use "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" using "MM" for month number. It might also be necessary to change the locale because the text might contain non-ascii-digits (not quite clear from your description).

Comment: @Meno yes you are right, but that was not the problem. in fact this should not even fire parse exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I had such exception was not related to Date Format rather that it was related to the source text file itself. turns out that the file was saved as unicode format while it should be saved as UTF-8 format. that's the reason why the data looked corrupt in the exception while I can read it from the file normally it was not processed through my application.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the date you are getting from your array has some characters that SimpleDateFormat cannot understand, put array[4] in a logger or another line where you can debug and see exactly what you are trying to parse.